# Large oversleep in Java thread occurs without GC interference and with low machine load

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, garbage-collection, udp

In a fairly complex application I am developing I have the following code in a thread:

```
long T = System.currentTimeMillis();
Thread.sleep(waitNow);
T = System.currentTimeMillis()-T;
if (T > waitNow*5) {
    System.out.println("Overslept "+T+" > "+waitNow);
}
```

This thread oversleeps on some occasions and produces output like this:

```
Overslept 10010 > 10
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** I am aware that the contract of the Thread.sleep method allows it to oversleep however this behaviour is strange given the size of the oversleep (10 seconds instead of 10 milliseconds).

The thread mostly sleeps an amount close to the specified time (11-15ms) however for some reason when the application is running it will sleep much longer (10 seconds+) and may do this a number of times over a few minutes (maybe as much as twice or three times a minute).

The thread is a normal priority thread.

There are about 35 threads in total in the application.

I have used jconsole and verified that the garbage collector is not running during these sleeps and that when the GC does run it is very fast (jconsole reports it taking around 30-50ms).

The app is allocated 256m of memory (-Xmx) but the heap is not using close to that amount (maybe around 30m) and a test app that specifically pushes the memory limit of the VM and at the same times has another thread trying to sleep does not hit the same issue.

This particular thread sends UDP messages however it sends these at a relatively low rate (around 20x 510 byte messages per second - 10k/sec).

The thread isn't interrupted since it continues on to finish the timing and print out the message about oversleeping.

The JRE is 1.7.0_45 build 18 running on a 2013 Retina Macbook pro 13" running OSX Mavericks.

Since my test app doesn't also oversleep at the same time this app does (in fact the test app doesn't oversleep at all) this would suggest it is not a clock update issue and is something particular to this app / JVM however I can't think of anything that would cause this, in fact aside from consuming a large amount of resources on the machine I can't think of any way for one thread inside Java to affect the amount of time another thread sleeps for which leads me to suspect it is something odd within the JVM or OS.

**The question is:**

Does anyone know what are the possible causes of the thread oversleeping?

What could the app (or anything else) be doing that wouldn't involve high memory using in the JVM or high CPU usage on the machine that might affect this?

Comment: What is the load on the box?  Are there other threads that are spinning?  Are there higher priority threads running?

Comment: The Java thread scheduler is known to be generally unfair and gives no guarantees that a specific thread will receive time.  Do all your threads include periodic `yield()` calls, _especially_ higher priority threads?

Comment: is that the exact code in question?  there's nothing else between those lines?  and waitNow isn't modifiable by another thread or anything?

Comment: This is the exact code, there is nothing between the lines.  I'm trying to run a test to get an exact note of the CPU as reported by the OS (the problem isn't always consistent) but jconsole when I saw the issue was reporting very low CPU usage like 5%.  There may be other higher priority threads however nothing is consuming large amounts of CPU during that time so I don't see why this thread would get starved?

Comment: Activity Monitor (OS) reports CPU of around 10% (90% idle)

Comment: A wild guess: Mavericks power management. Can you try it on others OS X versions or other platforms? See http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/06/how-os-x-mavericks-works-its-power-saving-magic/

Answer (score 2):

I had similar situation in my practice, it turned out to be a problem with JVM [safe points](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html).

For diagnostic you can use following options:

- `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` - it prints all STW pauses not only related to GC
- `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics` - prints safe points details
- `-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` - make JVM report every safe point

In my case, root cause was in application code (probably code have been triggering some bug in JIT).

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is usually something to do with the OS.  It is such a common problem there are tools to measure how badly your scheduling is. Most notably http://www.jhiccup.com/  However, hiccups of 5 - 50 ms are more common.

Multi second delays are likely to be some disk IO or something very serious e.g. perhaps your thread is being swapped to disk.

Comment: I can try this however the docs say "The hiccups measured are NOT stalls caused by the application's code. They are stalls caused by the platform that would be visible to and affect any application thread running on the platform at the time of the stall".  However I have had a thread doing constant 1s sleeps at the same time as this thread and it has been unaffected?

Comment: I should point out the thread doing the 1s sleeps was in a different JVM.

Comment: jHiccup seems to measure hiccups however it doesn't appear to have any information on why they are happening / what can be done to resolve them?  Why would this thread be being swapped to disk on a lightly loaded system?  Does this indicate an issue in the JVM or in the OS or machine hardware?

Comment: Testing with threads the same as jHiccup shows that another thread in the same JVM is also halting the same (same time, same delay) as the original thread however two other JVM processes (one the same JVM, one a different JVM) do not suffer any delays which would suggest it is constrained one way or another to the original JVM.  Anybody got any ideas about what the application threads in the original JVM could be doing that could affect this?

Comment: @user3058830 I can't imagine the JVM or hardware being the cause of such a long delay, largely because they are not directly involved in scheduling. Scheduling is the OS's job.  The JVM only major delay is GC stop-the-world collections and while they can take 10 seconds or more, they should be really obvious.  I suggest running `-verbose:gc` just to be sure you are not getting massive collections at this time.